Why is this for-loop stuck on the second iteration in C?
In C, I am creating a program that uses WinAPI. For this program, I am writing a function that will enable the specified privileges. Here is what I have:
void EnablePrivileges(LPCWSTR awszPrivileges[], DWORD dwCount){
     HANDLE hToken;
     if (!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, &hToken)) {
          printf("Failed to open process token. Error: %lu\n", GetLastError());
          return;
     }
     TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp;
     tp.PrivilegeCount = dwCount;
     for (DWORD i = 0; i < dwCount; ++i) {
          wprintf(TEXT("Privilege constant: %ls | Iterator value: %i\n"), awszPrivileges[i], i);
          if(!LookupPrivilegeValueW(NULL, awszPrivileges[i], &tp.Privileges[i].Luid)) {
               printf("Failed to lookup privilege value. Error: %lu\n", GetLastError());
               CloseHandle(hToken);
               return;
          }
          tp.Privileges[i].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
     }
     if (!AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &tp, sizeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES), NULL, NULL)) {
          printf("Failed to adjust token privileges. Error: %lu\n", GetLastError());
     } else {
          printf("Token privileges adjusted successfully.\n");
     }
     CloseHandle(hToken);
}

int main() {
     LPCWSTR awszPrivileges[] = {SE_TAKE_OWNERSHIP_NAME, SE_AUDIT_NAME, SE_RESTORE_NAME};
     EnablePrivileges(awszPrivileges, 3);
     system("pause");
     return 0;
}


It compiles with zero errors.
However, when I then run it with administrative privileges, it gives the following:
Privilege constant: SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege | Iterator value: 0
Privilege constant: SeAuditPrivilege | Iterator value: 1
Privilege constant: SeAuditPrivilege | Iterator value: 1
Privilege constant: SeAuditPrivilege | Iterator value: 1
Privilege constant: SeAuditPrivilege | Iterator value: 1
Privilege constant: SeAuditPrivilege | Iterator value: 1

... and so on.
It also did this when it was only two privileges attempting to be enabled. However, it works successfully with only one.
What is causing the for-loop to behave like this? What is the fix for this error?

Please do not tag spam. C, C#, and C++ are not the same language because they start with the letter C, any more than a car, a cat, and a carrot are related. Please use only the tag that actually applies to the language you're using. If you're not sure whether you're using C or C++, stop trying to write code until you figure it out, because you're not going to get anywhere.

@Chris It is C, but I am confident that the some problem would occur with C++.

Thinking the code might have the same issues does not excuse tag abuse. Please remove the tag that does not directly apply to the code you have posted here in this question.

@KenWhite I am writing in C, I made this abundantly clear. The reason I also tagged "C++" is because I am confident the error would also persist into this language. I also tried compiling with a C++ compiler, and the error remained.

You declared the stack variable TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp; -- you cannot access elements in the "any size" array like you're currently doing with tp.Privileges[i] because that's addressing off the end of the data structure. This structure is designed to be allocated with a size that reflects the actual memory required for the array, so that you can address off the end of the Privileges field. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-token_privileges

Your excuse for misusing the tag is irrelevant. Tags have meaning and relevance here, and you should only use tags that actually apply to the content of your post. If your code is in C, then adding the C++ tag is incorrect use of the tag system. Do not tag spam.

You're addressing off the end of tp.Privileges. That array has a size of 1. As stated in the documentation:

Important  The constant ANYSIZE_ARRAY is defined as 1 in the public header Winnt.h. To create this array with more than one element, you must allocate sufficient memory for the structure to take into account additional elements.

You must allocate a (properly aligned) block of memory that is at least sizeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES) + (dwCount - 1) * sizeof(LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES), and initialize your TOKEN_PRIVILEGES object there.

The more conventional way to determine the size is by having the compiler do the math, i.e., offsetof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES, Privileges[dwCount]) (use FIELD_OFFSET() if your compiler doesn't support offsetof()). Rationale behind the trailing array of size 1: Why do some structures end with an array of size 1?,
